# TYPO3 10.4.21 Pages accessible only via their id

Tags: apache, redirect, typo3, typo3-10.x

Following a migration, I am trying to reconfigure TYPO3.
The backend is accessible by its url and I manage to connect. But the home page for example gives me the following error: ***The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: No site configuration found.***

All pages are not accessible by their url normally but are accessible through different query parameters, like */index.php?id=2&L=0*.

I already tried to replace the .htaccess with the basic one provided by TYPO3, I also checked the Apache configuration and everything seems to be ok. I am not familiar with the TYPO3 CMS so I don't know if some of these configurations are done directly in its files. To me, it seems to be a mod_rewrite problem but I can't find it.

Someone would have a solution or at least a track to solve this problem?

Comment: This error occurs in https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/v10.4.21/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Middleware/PageResolver.php#L54-L60. Judging by the code there may be a properly configured SiteConfig but it couldnt be found / mapped to your request. Please verify if  the base and basevariant domains you have configured in the siteconfig match the domain youre calling with.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message that you've posted it seems that the site configuration is missing. In the TYPO3 backend you can create new site configuration via Site Management => Sites.

Please check the [site handling documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/CreateNew.html) for details.

Comment: I didn't specify it but, obviously, the site configuration is present in the backend and correct. That's why I can't find the source of the problem.